# Tfs and nuget: project files are forever in check out after build with restore nuget packages

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, nuget

MS VS 2012
I have solution in tfs with enabled nuget packages restore. Every time when I build solution all my project files are cheked out with this changes:

```
<Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets" Condition="Exists('$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets')" />
<Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets'))" />
</Target>
```

How to fix this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of NuGet v2.7, *MSBuild-Integrated Package Restore* has been deprecated and replaced with *Automatic Package Restore*.

See documentation on how to migrate your solution to the new feature: [Migrating MSBuild-Integrated solutions to use Automatic Package Restore](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/migrating-to-automatic-package-restore)

To learn more about *Automatic Package Restore* see 
[NuGet Package Restore](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore)

Both articles discuss how this effects TFS integration.